# PlayStation store error?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, psn

On the ps3 when I go to install a game I already bought it just tells me a error code and I don’t get to install my game and now I’m sitting here looking stuff up but I’m not finding a good answer to how I could fix this if someone has a answer that would really help.   (The error code is 80029509)

Answer (score 4):

**Unfortunately, it appears there is little you can do about this issue**, as it isn't an issue with your console. It is being caused because thousands of PS3 players are panicking and rushing to download their games, causing a massive amount of traffic to be pushed through, which the server has some trouble with. According to [Push](https://www.pushsquare.com/news/2021/04/ps3_owners_facing_wide-spread_problems_downloading_games_ahead_of_ps_store_closure),

> It [the errors] could be a case that PS3’s servers are simply experiencing
> unprecedented traffic right now; Sony may have scaled down support for
> the system over the years, but now there’s been a sudden surge in
> activity it’s struggling to cope.

You could try setting an alarm to very early in your current time zone, as less people are likely to be online, but this only has a slight chance of working.

Comment: Maybe set an alarm for very early in the morning in your timezone, and try your downloads again. Server load might be lesser then :)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Great idea! I’ll add that in.